# Image modification tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

We have a number of tags relating to image modification:

- [image-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-editing) (189 Q)
- [image-processing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) (85 Q)
- [image-manipulation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-manipulation) (25 Q)
- [image-transparancy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-transparancy) (10 Q).

None of the tags have a definition, and they are used almost interchangeably (except for the last).

There are actually a few different topics:

- how to achieve a specific alteration in the content/appearance of an image ([image-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-editing)
- how to use an automated process to modify many images in the same way (either the image content or the files) ([image-processing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/image-processing))
- how to turn a collection of individual images into a single, combined package, like a video or album ([not-sure-what-that-tag-would-be-called](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/not-sure-what-that-tag-would-be-called))
- image transparency seems to be too granular for a separate tag; we would need separate tags for blurring, cropping, resizing, and all of the other common operations.

Questions:

- Are these topics different enough that they should have separate tags?
    (That will require retagging a significant portion of the 300+ questions.)
- Is there a way to do it that would be batter adhered to than past practice or are we wasting our time trying to maintain the separate topics?
- If we give up and just make the existing tags synonyms, what should the primary tag be (is there an all-encompassing term)?